# How to tell LINQ to skip where if condition is false?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

Refer to code below:

Instead of having so many if else statements:

```
List<T> GetTs(string createBy, bool isAdmin, string departmentCode, ...)
{
    if(isAdmin)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createBy))
        {
            var query = context.table
                        .Where(x => string.compare(x.createBy, createBy, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                        .ToList();
            return query;
        }
        else
        {
            var query = context.table.ToList();
            return query;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createBy))
        {
            var query = context.table
                        .Where(x => string.compare(x.departmentCode, departmentCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                        .Where(x => string.compare(x.createBy, createBy, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                        .ToList();
            return query;
        }
        else
        {
            var query = context.table
                        .Where(x => string.compare(x.departmentCode, departmentCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                        .ToList();
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Can I do this instead where it don't have so many if else statements:

```
var query  = context.table
                .Where(x => (!isAdmin)? string.compare(x.departmentCode, departmentCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) : SKIP THIS '.Where')
                .Where(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createBy))? string.compare(x.createBy, createBy, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) : SKIP THIS '.Where')
                //...
                .ToList();
```

How do I tell LINQ to skip the `.Where` if condition is false? possible?

Suggestion of Patrick Hofman from comment below works:

```
var query  = context.table
                .Where(x => (!isAdmin)? string.compare(x.departmentCode, departmentCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) : true)
                .Where(x => (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(createBy))? string.compare(x.createBy, createBy, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0) : true)
                //...
                .ToList();
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense

Comment: This is a very confused question. you need to do some reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you provide a more clear example? _What_ exactly should not be executed?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem....what are you trying to achieve? Note that simply `true` instead of `SKIP THIS WHERE` has the effect you want.

Comment: Why skip it and not just return `true`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman like this `.Where(x => (true)? x.column1 == true : true)`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is severely confused, there has been no attempt to clarify the question, and no attempt at research

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the intent (to conditionally apply predicates), then basically: do the composition differently:

```
IQueryable<Whatever> query = context.Table;
if(condition1)
    query = query.Where(x => x.column1);
if(condition2)
    query = query.Where(x => x.column2);
//...etc
var list = query.ToList();
```

You could probably wrap that in an extension method like

```
static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool condition,
        Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate)
    => condition ? query.Where(predicate) : query;
```

and:

```
var list= context.Table.WhereIf(condition1, x => x.column1)
                       .WhereIf(condition2, x => x.column2)
                       // ...
                       .ToList();
```

however, I probably *wouldn't* do that, as in many cases it will require constructing an unnecessary additional expression tree.

Comment: I am not sure if that answers the question. I don't even think I understand the question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've made my interpretation more explicit - you're right that the question is ambiguous

Comment: Don't have `WhereIf`.

Comment: If I do composition differently, I might have many conditions and combinations.

Comment: @Pop I literally added the code for `WhereIf` in the answer; as for "might have many conditions and combinations": yes, that can happen

Comment: "in many cases it will require constructing an unnecessary additional expression tree" - why is that?

Comment: @Evk imagine we call `.WhereIf(name != null, x => x.Name == name)` - seems reasonable, yes? that creates a *non-trivial* object even if `name` is `null` (so it would be ignored); you can see the generated C# (or something like it) [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mgravell/f917e5a279d78f4054fc3494604ba0a4/raw/3e66fcb746f152a958b491ae4ecaf2f19a747d4f/url) - I've included a second version that does the test via a simple `if` - note that the expression tree is *not* generated. Sorry, you'll have to copy/paste the sharplab url from the gist - too long for a comment here!

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, that's pretty obvious actually, not sure why I misunderstood.

Comment: @MarcGravell I means I don't have `WhereIf` option.

Comment: @Pop and once again: I literally included the code for that in the answer; `static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, bool condition, Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) => condition ? query.Where(predicate) : query;` is the entirety of that method